# How to solve complex equations in two variables in python?

Tags: python-2.7, math, linear-algebra

I want to solve this given equation.
`A+B = 0`; where

```
A = (x-40+1j*(y+30))-(120+0j);  
B = (x-60)+1j*(y+30)-(70*(0.866-0.5j))
```

Can anyone hint how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

It's less of a programming problem and more of an algebra with complex variables problem.

You have two unknowns, x and y, and one equation.

The best you can do is rewrite to express y as a function of x.  There will be many solutions that will satisfy it.

It appears to be complex as well, so the solution will be a function in the complex plane.

I think my algebra's correct - check me:

```
y = -j*(140.31 - x -j*47.5)
```

Plot it - that's your solution.

I just asked Wolfram Alpha to check me:

[image]

Comment: If the OP doesn't want to have to do manual math, s/he could use the Python module [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) to solve `A+B=0` for a single variable, plug it back in, use `numpy.roots` to get the zeroes of the resulting polynomial.

Comment: "Doesn't want to do manual math" - I don't think computers and software should ever be used as a substitute for thinking.  This is little more than high school algebra.  And it's not the same as zeroes of a polynomial, because there's a finite number of those.  This is a function.

Comment: I'm not saying as a substitute for thinking, I just mean maybe this is example output from a repeated process in which case solving the equation by hand isn't viable.

Comment: That's a guess.  There's nothing in the original question to suggest that interpretation.  But in that case I'd say that a symbolic solver would still be better, because it's not a root finding problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is pure mathematics. Set z=x+j*y, then your equation amounts to

```
A = z+(-40+1j*30)-(120+0j);  
B = z+(-60+1j*30)-70*(0.866-0.5j)
```

And so A+B=0 is the same as

```
-2*z=C=(-40+1j*30)-(120+0j)+(-60+1j*30)-70*(0.866-0.5j)
or
z=-0.5*C
```

which is a simple computation in complex arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I want to ask if there is any way to solve these types of equations by comparing real parts and imaginary parts of both LHS and RHS.

Comment: Can you post some surrounding code? Or at least some surrounding context, it is not really clear what you want to achieve in the greater picture. -- Treat complex numbers as 2D vectors and you get automatically the separation. If you somehow are computing this with symbolic variables, then you have to somehow encode the constraint that x and y are real.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(x):
    A = (x[0]-40+`1j`*(x[1]+30))-(120+`0j`)
    B = (x[0]-60)+`1j`*(x[1]+30)-(70*(0.866-0.5j))
    return [np.real(A+B),np.imag(A+B)]
sol = optimize.root(fun, [10,10], method='hybr') 
sol
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add an explanation to your code on why this solves the questions? This makes it easier for future readers to understand, thanks!